# Backbone Router for React JS UI

Tags: reactjs, backbone.js, url-routing

I want to create a website that uses React JS as the handler for the UI component and Backbone JS for the routing. I don't like to follow the usual routing, for example:

```
www.domain-name.com/blog1
www.domain-name.com/blog1/post1
www.domain-name.com/blog1/profile
```

I would like to achieve a routing similar to this:

```
blog1.domain-name.com
blog1.domain-name.com/post1
blog1.domain-name.com/profile
```

Can someone advice me where to start because I can't get my footing. If you can give me tutorial or books that can help me, that would be great.

Pardon me if this seemed to be a broad question.

Comment: have a look at this https://github.com/rackt/react-router

Comment: The answer to this question is strictly server side, and doesn't have anything to do with react, backbone, or client side routing.  It also involves editing your DNS.

Comment: @Retozi I already did. But Backbone Router is much stable than react-router, I think.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand Oh! Okay! Still blurry, but will look into that.

Comment: @Holmes: What makes you think that? Backbone Router is a quite thin wrapper around the history api, so is react-router. However, you need to adjust the Backbone Router to make it work with react, which you seem to struggle with, so I would strongly suggest to use a library that is specifically made for React.

I use react-router in production and have not experienced an issue so far

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but there is a simple way to use your Backbone Router with React components / views. Just declare your routes like usual in Backbone, and have each route render the proper react component:

In your router:

```
routes: {
  'signup': 'signup',
  'posts/new': 'newPost'
   ....
}

newPost: function() {
  reactMount = $('.react-mount')[0]
  React.renderComponent(MyNewPostReactComponent, whateverProps, reactMount)
}
```

Then you just need to have the proper DOM element with `.react-mount`. You can have this be the empty `body`, and each of your routes just renders a full react component, for example.